# How to test API without mocks and spies?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

There is the service that contains 2 methods:

```
export class CounterService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getGirls(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/girls');   // return some JSON
  }

  getObservableValue() {
    return of('observable value');
  }
}
```

I try to write unit-test:

```
describe('CounterService', () => {
  let service: CounterService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [CounterService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(CounterService);
  });

  it(
    'test should wait for CounterService.getObservableValue',
    waitForAsync(() => {
      service
        .getObservableValue()
        .subscribe((value) => expect(value).toBe('observable value'));
    })
  );

  it(
    'test should wait for CounterService.getGirls',
    waitForAsync(() => {
      service
        .getGirls()
        .subscribe((value) => expect(value).toBeTruthy());
    })
  );
});
```

As a result test '**test should wait for CounterService.getObservableValue**' is successful, but test '**test should wait for CounterService.getGirls**' is not successful.

Jasmine displays the following message:

> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS: test should wait for CounterService.getGirls

Please help me test **getGirls()** WITHOUT spy and any mocks. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `HttpTestingController` to send requests.

```
describe('CounterService', () => {
  let service: CounterService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [CounterService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(CounterService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // ensure no outstanding API calls
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it(
    'test should wait for CounterService.getObservableValue',
    waitForAsync(() => {
      service
        .getObservableValue()
        .subscribe((value) => expect(value).toBe('observable value'));
    })
  );

  it(
    'test should wait for CounterService.getGirls',
    waitForAsync(() => {
      service
        .getGirls()
        .subscribe((value) => expect(value).toBeTruthy());

      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/girls');
      expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      
      // flush this response
      req.flush(['Alicia', 'Tina', 'Michelle']);
    })
  );
});
```

[This](https://betterprogramming.pub/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf) is a good blog post for you to help with Http testing.